# SQL Error Converting Data to Int When I am Not Asking It To

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

I have the following SQL statement. In it I need to convert some numbers stored as varchar to decimal in order to sum them.

When I run this SQL against my constraints I get this message:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1635.34' to data
>   type int.

Which baffles me because I am casting my data as decimal. It also baffles me because when I use different constraints that have the same type of data in the field (`1234.56` type of format) it works. That data is in the `TotalPremium` field.

(My logic is a bit complex so that is why SQL statement is complex. I am posting all of it for clarity sake. Also, redesigning database table field type is not an option at this point.)

```
SELECT Account_No, version_num, LineOfBus, ProductNo, QuoteNo, Sum(Cast(TotalPremium as Decimal(16,2))) TotalPremium
    FROM 
    (SELECT t.Account_No, t.version_num, 
        CASE 
            WHEN t.PackageIndicator = '1' THEN 'Package' Else t.Lob 
        END AS LineOfBus,
        t.ProductNo, t.QuoteNo, Cast(COALESCE(t.TotalPremium,0) as decimal(16,2)) TotalPremium 
        FROM uAccountProductInfo as T
        WHERE t.version_num IN
            (SELECT sqVersionNumber.version_num
                FROM
                /* this captures unique package product records (or just stand alone records as well) */
                (SELECT DISTINCT sqUnique.version_num, Count(sqUnique.version_num) VersionCount 
                    FROM
                    /* grab list of all uniquer version, product, quote combinations (use distinct to combine package */
                        (SELECT DISTINCT version_num, productNo, quoteNo
                            FROM uAccountProductInfo
                            WHERE Account_No = '1172014' /* pass as parameter */
                                AND ProductNo IN ('6472930', '6474927') /* pass as parameter */
                                AND QuoteNo IN ('724185-01', '881957-08') /* pass as parameter */
                        ) AS sqUnique
                    GROUP BY version_num
                    HAVING Count(version_num) = 2 /* pass as variable based on number of products, quotes */
                ) as sqVersionNumber
            )
        AND t.Account_no = '1172014' /* pass as parameter */
        AND t.ProductNo IN ('6472930', '6474927') /* pass as parameter */
        AND t.QuoteNo IN ('724185-01', '881957-08') /* pass as parameter */) as sqLOB
    GROUP BY Account_No, version_num, LineOfBus, ProductNo, QuoteNo
```

Comment: I'm guessing you have an implicit conversion somewhere, but I can't see it in the code. Can you post the estimated execution plan here: [Paste The Plan @ brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)? instructions: [How to Use Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/).

Comment: What field type is `uAccountProductInfo.PackageIndicator`? If it's not numeric, then you should change that CASE statement to `t.PackageIndicator = '1'`

Comment: @SqlZim - [Execution Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJYLUWZyZ)

Comment: @JNevill - fair point. I forgot to add that in my query. That is not causing the issue though.

Comment: Are 'Package' and t.Lob same data type?

Comment: @Wendy - Yes they are both varchar

Comment: Is this query written as-is throwing this error, or is it when parameters are passed in that it misbehaves (asking because of the comments in the sql).

Comment: @JNevill - As is. Comments are for my sake when I need to parameterize (is that a word?!) it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that SQL Server does not guarantee the order of evaluation of operations.  You clearly have something improper in the field.  In SQL Server 2012+, use `try_convert()`:

```
SELECT Sum(try_convert(decimal(16, 2), TotalPremium ))) as TotalPremium
```

In earlier versions, use `case`:

```
SELECT Sum(case when isnumeric(TotalPremium) = 1 then  convert(decimal(16, 2), TotalPremium)) end) as TotalPremium
```

`isnumeric()` is not perfect, but it should be good enough for your purposes.

Comment: If the error was coming from there, then it would say "Error converting data type varchar to numeric." e.g. `SELECT Sum(convert(decimal(16, 2), 'oops' )) as TotalPremium` ... http://rextester.com/PXH65296

Comment: Accepting this answer as converting with case in both places is what solved it finally. That said, the other answers helped as well and it was really a combination of all 3 that solved it. I will post my final code that works as soon as time allows.

Comment: @SqlZim . . . In that case, I apologize for the accusation, but the coincidence was pretty strong.

Comment: I don't believe I've ever shown you anything but goodwill, why would you think that I would do something like that?

Comment: Linoff and prosper...get it?

Comment: It bugs me that there is no real way to prove I didn't downvote other than voting. I have 4 all time downvotes on my summary page from downvoting questions that have long since been deleted, so that's not helpful. So +1 as of whatever timestamp this comment gets. https://i.gyazo.com/ffbde350ef63e30b75ffee7603ab18ff.png

Answer (score 3):

Cast `t.TotalPremium` to decimal before coalescing. Your query is doing `coalesce` on a string and an integer, then casting the result to decimal.  <s>`Try using`0.0`instead of`0`as well.`</s>

**edit** I do not actually think using `0.0` rather than `0` is a good idea, aside from readability.  If that is the goal, cast it to the same decimal datatype.   Otherwise, this could be construed as a datatype dominant over `decimal`.  `0` as `int` or `varchar` should not take precedence over our value casted to a decimal.

Comment: I understand the answer (although totally wrong).  I don't understand the upvote.  The order of the conversion and `NULL` comparison has nothing to do with the type conversion issue.

Comment: @GordonLinoff `select coalesce('1635.34',0)` returns the following error: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1635.34' to data type int." http://rextester.com/KFVER84579

Comment: It is my understanding that in the case of the OP's query, `int` is the datatype will take precedence.  In my suggestion, decimal will have precedence in the `null` comparison.  Is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: @GordonLinoff It is not by any means "totally wrong".  He is not saying anything about "the order of conversion and null" (whatever that means).  He is saying that the data types of the expression input array to the coalesce function cannot contain elements of type varchar and integer/decimal, so the varchar value(s) must be cast to a numeric data type so that they can be evaluated with the OPs numeric default/Nth term.  This is why this fails: select coalesce('1.1',0.0), and this succeeds: select coalesce(cast('1.1' as decimal),0.0).

Comment: This helped a lot. Just as important to solving problem as other issue. Also helped my understanding (and of course seeing how I was mismatching datatypes). I posted the final answer as well which I used elements of all 3 answers.

Comment: Glad to have been able to help, Scott.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Incorporating the concept in this answer actually got me to the point where your answer then solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `isnull()` instead of `coalesce()`, though it would still be better practice to use the same datatype as RexMaison points out.

```
create table t (TotalPremium varchar(16));
insert into t values (''),(null),('1635.34');

/* no error */
select isnull(t.TotalPremium,0) 
from t;

/* no error */
select coalesce(t.TotalPremium,'0')
from t;

/* error */
select coalesce(t.TotalPremium,0) 
from t;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/OHEJ71310

Comment: Thanks for the help. I posted an answer with the follow version that works, with elements of all 3 answers given.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting final code that worked after incorporating elements of all 3 answers.

```
SELECT Account_No, version_num, LineOfBus, ProductNo, QuoteNo, 
        SUM(CASE 
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(TotalPremium) = 1 THEN CONVERT(decimal(16,2),TotalPremium) 
            END) As TotalPremium 
    FROM 
    (SELECT t.Account_No, t.version_num, 
        CASE 
            WHEN ISNull(t.PackageIndicator,'0') = '1' THEN 'Package' Else t.Lob 
        END AS LineOfBus,
        t.ProductNo, t.QuoteNo, 
        ISNull(CASE 
                    WHEN ISNUMERIC(t.TotalPremium) = 1 THEN CONVERT(decimal(16,2),t.TotalPremium) 
                END, 0) TotalPremium 
        FROM uAccountProductInfo as T
        WHERE t.version_num IN
            (SELECT sqVersionNumber.version_num
                FROM
                /* this captures unique package product records (or just stand alone records as well) */
                (SELECT DISTINCT sqUnique.version_num, Count(sqUnique.version_num) VersionCount 
                    FROM
                    /* grab list of all uniquer version, product, quote combinations (use distinct to combine package */
                        (SELECT DISTINCT version_num, productNo, quoteNo
                            FROM uAccountProductInfo
                            WHERE Account_No = '1172014' /* pass as parameter */
                                AND ProductNo IN ('6472930', '6474927') /* pass as parameter */
                                AND QuoteNo IN ('724185-01', '881957-08') /* pass as parameter */
                        ) AS sqUnique
                    GROUP BY version_num
                    HAVING Count(version_num) = 2 /* pass as variable based on number of products, quotes */
                ) as sqVersionNumber
            )
        AND t.Account_no = '1172014' /* pass as parameter */
        AND t.ProductNo IN ('6472930', '6474927') /* pass as parameter */
        AND t.QuoteNo IN ('724185-01', '881957-08') /* pass as parameter */) as sqLOB
    GROUP BY Account_No, version_num, LineOfBus, ProductNo, QuoteNo
```